# Angular router setup with full screen (i.e. no Header & Footer) on some routes

Tags: angular

In my Angular (v.7) application, I want practically all of the routes to have a navbar and a footer, which works fine, i.e. my app.component.html looks something like :

```
<header></header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

My routes look like:

```
  {
    path: "foo",
    loadChildren: "./foo/foo.module#FooModule",
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "bar",
    loadChildren: "./bar/bar.module#BarModule",
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]
  }
```

For some routes, I require a full screen setup where no header or footer is visible.

I want to solve it via routes, not via directives, as they make everything unweildy and I do not wish to handle additional state like an "isHeaderVisible" flag.

It feels like there should be a good router setup which accomplishes what I aim to do.

So what I essentially want is to have my main component still be like above, and another one to simply have a

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

which receives the other routes

I can't figure out a route setup that works for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 wrapper component such as `PublicComponent` and `AuthenticatedComponent`

Suppose that structure is like this:

```
- AppComponent
--- PublicComponent
------ LoginComponent
------ RegisterComponent
--- AuthenticatedComponent
------ DashboardComponent
------ SettingsComponent
```

Then your routes be like:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticatedComponent,
    children: [
        {
           path: "foo",
           loadChildren: "./foo/foo.module#FooModule"
         },
        {
           path: "bar",
           loadChildren: "./bar/bar.module#BarModule",
         },
   canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
   canActivateChild: [AuthenticationGuard]
},
{
    path: '',
    component: PublicComponent,
    children: [
        {
           path: "login",
           component: LoginComponent
         },
         {
           path: "register",
           component: RegisterComponent
         },

}
```

And you need to place `router-outlet`s accordingly:

AppComponent

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

AuthenticatedComponent

```
<header></header>
<sidebar></sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

PublicComponent

```
<sidebar></sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<another-component></another-component>
```

Hope this give you a hint